# gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3') not working on ios use phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, youtube-data-api

I build an app use youtube and Map api with phonegap.
Testing on device with Phonegap Developer app.

```
var API_KEY = xxxx;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad');
});

function handleClientLoad() {
    alert("msg 1");
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {
        alert("msg 2");            
        $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=handleMapsLoad&key=' + API_KEY);
    });
}
function handleMapsLoad() {
    alert("msg 3");

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


}
```

Everything work fine on Chrome simulation extension. and Android OS: shown: msg 1. msg 2, msg 3.

But not work with iOS, **only msg 1** not msg 2, msg 3. and an error msg: `[phonegap] [console.log] Error in Success callbackId: Geolocation191878646 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google`

p/s: ip 6s iOS 10.0.2, i checked, the API_KEY unrestricted.

Thanks any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched and tested all solutions for 3 weeks, but have not found a solution. I found the problem caused by the `PhoneGap Developer App`, not the `YouTube API` or another configuration.

The problem is only resolved when the app is installed on a real device (not a simulator) via `TestFlight` or `iTunes` (published app), where everything works fine.

Cause:
- The `gapi` library uses an `iframe` for network requests, but the `PhoneGap Developer App` on `iTunes` (current version 1.7.6) does not allow `iframe` usage.

Comment: Guys and don't forget to add     <allow-navigation href="https://accounts.google.com" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://content.googleapis.com" /> because you will not get an error on a simulator with gapi.client.load, although you still need to setup App Transport Security Settings properly!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
SOLVED adding the following directives to `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="https://*.google.com/*" />
<access origin="https://*.googleapis.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.google.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.googleapis.com/*" />
```

and `wss:` protocol to the Content-Security-Policy (meta tag in index.html), like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src * gap://ready file: wss:;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            127.0.0.1:*
            http://*.google.com
            http://*.googleapis.com
            https://*.google.com
            https://*.googleapis.com;
">
```

Explaination: you have to allow iframe generated by `gapi.client.load()` to navigate to google APIs.